# filter log message with "az webapp log tail"

Tags: azure, azure-cli

Is it possible to filter out message logs from Azure by the using the Azure CLI, like this

```
az webapp log tail
```

I see some posts mention the parameter `--filter`, however, it looks like that filter has been retired, isn't it?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/log?view=azure-cli-latest#az_webapp_log_tail

Is there any workaround for that?

Edited: to add a screenshot
[image: Azure CLI]

Answer (score 3):

Looks like this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs#in-cloud-shell) is old, there is no `--filter` parameter both in `az webapp log tail --help` or this link [`az webapp log tail`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/log?view=azure-cli-latest#az_webapp_log_tail) in the latest version.

If you just want to filter with `Error`, you could use `--only-show-errors` parameter.

```
az webapp log tail --name appname --resource-group myResourceGroup --only-show-errors
```

Or if you want to increase logging verbosity, you could use `--verbose`.

```
az webapp log tail --name appname --resource-group myResourceGroup --verbose
```

Answer (score 0):

[Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs#in-azure-portal) specific events, like Error

```
az webapp log tail --name appname --resource-group myResourceGroup --filter Error
```

Comment: yeah, it also see that article, but don't know why the --filter not recognized. I edited my question to add a screen shot

Comment: `--filter` has been removed or is an undocumented parameter because right now do not appears when trying [`az webapp log tail --help`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/log?view=azure-cli-latest#az_webapp_log_tail). May be do you refer to `--query`